# how to draw part of a cone in rgl?

Tags: r, rgl

I would like to use `rgl` to draw part of a cone, as on [this web page](https://www.blocklayer.com/cone-patterns.aspx) (click "3d cone model")

I would like to specify three parameters (bottom radius, top radius, height) then draw a cone in `rgl` -- is this possible/easy? how? I don't see any mention of drawing cones in the `rgl` docs.

[image: cone view 1]

[image: cone 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `cylinder3d` function can do that.  You specify two points (the center of the top and bottom), and the two radii.  For example,

```
pts <- cbind(c(0, 0), c(0, 1), c(0, 0))   # the centers
radii <- c(0.2, 0.4)
cone <- cylinder3d(pts, radii, sides = 64)
shade3d(cone, col = "lightblue")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: more generally, `demo("shapes3d")` can be useful in showing you some of the other options when working with 3D shapes in RGL (translation, rotation, mesh vs wireframe, etc.)